# Awk script to delete some block pattern

Tags: awk

I have the following file with a lot of entries:

[...]

```
edit "ip_address_1"
    set uuid 8b6d9bd0-9fe7-51ee-d54d-d904bfc9a7e1
    set associated-interface "interface1"
    set subnet 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.255
next
edit "ip_address_2"
    set uuid a3465e68-9fe7-51ee-cf95-96b35ab0532e
    set associated-interface "interface1"
    set subnet 10.0.0.2 255.255.255.255
next
edit "ip_address_3"
    set uuid c1b62e20-9fef-51ee-5915-14502d40552e
    set associated-interface "interface2"
    set subnet 10.0.0.3 255.255.255.255
next
```

I'd like to use an awk script to delete all blocks **which don't contain**

```
set associated-interface "interface1"
```

so the final result should be

```
edit "ip_address_1"
    set uuid 8b6d9bd0-9fe7-51ee-d54d-d904bfc9a7e1
    set associated-interface "interface1"
    set subnet 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.255
next
edit "ip_address_2"
    set uuid a3465e68-9fe7-51ee-cf95-96b35ab0532e
    set associated-interface "interface1"
    set subnet 10.0.0.2 255.255.255.255
next
```

I tried something like this

```
awk  '/edit/, /next/ {if ($0 ~ /set associated interface1/) {print $0}}'  address.fgt
```

but the output contains only the lines with:

```
set associated interface1
set associated interface1
```

instead I'd like to have the all block.
Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `gnu-awk` solution:

```bash
awk -v RS='\nnext\n' '{ORS = RT} /set associated-interface "interface1"/' file

edit "ip_address_1"
    set uuid 8b6d9bd0-9fe7-51ee-d54d-d904bfc9a7e1
    set associated-interface "interface1"
    set subnet 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.255
next
edit "ip_address_2"
    set uuid a3465e68-9fe7-51ee-cf95-96b35ab0532e
    set associated-interface "interface1"
    set subnet 10.0.0.2 255.255.255.255
next
```

**Details:**

- `RS='\nnext\n'` sets input record separator to `next` wrapped with line break on both sides
- `ORS = RT`: Sets output record separator same as the input record separator
- `/set associated-interface "interface1"/` prints each record that contain this substring

---

**2nd Solution (works in any awk version):**

```bash
awk '/^edit / {
   rec = 1
   s = $0
   next
}
rec {
   s = s ORS $0
}
/^next/ {
   if (s ~ /set associated-interface "interface1"/)
      print s
   rec = 0
}' file

edit "ip_address_1"
    set uuid 8b6d9bd0-9fe7-51ee-d54d-d904bfc9a7e1
    set associated-interface "interface1"
    set subnet 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.255
next
edit "ip_address_2"
    set uuid a3465e68-9fe7-51ee-cf95-96b35ab0532e
    set associated-interface "interface1"
    set subnet 10.0.0.2 255.255.255.255
next
```

[**Online Working Demo**](https://ideone.com/htDqwZ)

Comment: Mmm first solution doesn't produce output:

awk -v RS='\nnext\n' '{ORS = RT} /set associated-interface "interface1"/' address.fgt

awk --version
GNU Awk 4.0.2
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2012 Free Software Foundation.

Comment: May be you have DOS line breaks in input. You can try my **2nd solution** given above.

Comment: I convert to Linux carriage return but still no output. Both solutions don't work

Comment: Did you try 2nd solution as well?

Comment: [Here is a working demo](https://ideone.com/htDqwZ). You need to make sure that your actual input data is not different from the sample you've provided above.

Comment: Sorry it worked, it was my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```bash
awk '
  /edit/ {
    block = "";
    found = 0;
  }
  {
    block = block ORS $0;
  }
  /set associated-interface "interface1"/ {
    found = 1;
  }
  /next/ {
    if (found) {
      print block;
    }
  }
' your_file
```

**Explanation of the above script:**

1. When it encounters a line with `/edit/`, it inintializes the block variable with the current line and sets the found variable to `0`.
2. For each line, it appends the line to the block variable, separated by the [output record separator (ORS)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Output-Separators.html#Output-Separators-1).
3. When it encounters a line with `/set associated-interface "interface1"/`, it sets the found variable to `1`.
4. When it encounters a line with `/next/`, it checks if the found variable is set to `1`. If it is, it prints the entire block.

***[Working Demo](https://replit.com/@msankrit/StainedSnappyStrategy#main.sh)***

Answer (score 0):

[TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr) Lisp:

We can get the file as a big string, and remove the unwanted sections with a single regular expression, replaced by nothing:

```
$ txr -e '(flow (get-string)
            (regsub #/edit.*next\n&~.*set associated-interface "interface1".*/ "")
            put-string)' < data
edit "ip_address_1"
    set uuid 8b6d9bd0-9fe7-51ee-d54d-d904bfc9a7e1
    set associated-interface "interface1"
    set subnet 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.255
next
edit "ip_address_2"
    set uuid a3465e68-9fe7-51ee-cf95-96b35ab0532e
    set associated-interface "interface1"
    set subnet 10.0.0.2 255.255.255.255
next
```

Though TXR lacks many features of Perl regexes, but it does have regex intersection (`&`) and complement (`~`) operators.

Regex intersection and complement are often useful in this pattern:

```
WANTED_MATCH&~.*NOT_WANTED_CONTENT.*
```

The `WANTED_MATCH` pattern matches something more general than what we want. Then `.*NOT_WANTED_CONTENT.*` by itself matches all texts which contain `NOT_WANTED_CONTENT`. We complement that with `~`, and so it matches all other texts: those which don't have that content. Then we combine the two with `&`: texts  that match the wanted pattern, but also don't have that content.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'edit "ip_address_1"
    set uuid 8b6d9bd0-9fe7-51ee-d54d-d904bfc9a7e1
    set associated-interface "interface1"
    set subnet 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.255
next
edit "ip_address_2"
    set uuid a3465e68-9fe7-51ee-cf95-96b35ab0532e
    set associated-interface "interface1"
    set subnet 10.0.0.2 255.255.255.255
next
edit "ip_address_3"
    set uuid c1b62e20-9fef-51ee-5915-14502d40552e
    set associated-interface "interface2"
    set subnet 10.0.0.3 255.255.255.255
next' |
```

---

```
 mawk 'BEGIN { FS = "set associated-interface \"interface1\""
               RS = ORS = "\nnext\n" } 1 < NF'
```

---

```
edit "ip_address_1"
    set uuid 8b6d9bd0-9fe7-51ee-d54d-d904bfc9a7e1
    set associated-interface "interface1"
    set subnet 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.255
next
edit "ip_address_2"
    set uuid a3465e68-9fe7-51ee-cf95-96b35ab0532e
    set associated-interface "interface1"
    set subnet 10.0.0.2 255.255.255.255
next
```

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '
    { rec = rec $0 ORS }
    /^next$/ {
        if ( rec ~ /(^|\n)[[:blank:]]*set associated-interface "interface1"(\n|$)/ ) {
            printf "%s", rec
        }
        rec = ""
        next
    }
' file
edit "ip_address_1"
    set uuid 8b6d9bd0-9fe7-51ee-d54d-d904bfc9a7e1
    set associated-interface "interface1"
    set subnet 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.255
next
edit "ip_address_2"
    set uuid a3465e68-9fe7-51ee-cf95-96b35ab0532e
    set associated-interface "interface1"
    set subnet 10.0.0.2 255.255.255.255
next
```